# Role Based variable products

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a woocommerce store that sells variable products.

e.g Blowgun
variable:
single item
box of 4

Im trying to make it so variable products will not show the single item when logged in.
Ive got it to a point where itll hide the option label text but doesnt remove option all together.

[varaible options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiK8X.png)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'custom_hide_single_item_option', 10, 1);
function custom_hide_single_item_option($term_name)
{
    // Get the current user's roles
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = (array)$user->roles;

    // Define the roles to exclude
    $roles_to_exclude = array('reseller', 'reseller 1', 'administrator');

    // If the user has any of the excluded roles, remove the "Single Item (1pc)" option
    if (array_intersect($user_roles, $roles_to_exclude) && $term_name === 'Single Item (1pc)') {
        return false;
    }

    return $term_name;
}
```

Ive provided php snippet im using and screenshot shows results of that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand / see the problem in the description and/or image. The only thing i see is a dropdown with a possibility to buy 4. Do you want to remove the dropdown? In that case I don't think the PHP is the problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'hide_attribute_values_for_specific_user_roles', 10, 1);
function hide_attribute_values_for_specific_user_roles( $args ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = (array) $user->roles;

    $roles_to_exclude = array('reseller', 'reseller 1', 'administrator');

    if ( count( array_intersect( $user_roles, $roles_to_exclude ) ) > 0 ) {
        // Your attribute can have a different slug
        $attribute_slug_to_hide = 'pa_quantity';
        
        // This is a term (attribute option) slug, not its name! You may need to replace this value with the one you have on your website
        $attribute_value_to_hide = 'single-item-1pc'; 
        
        if ( isset( $args['attribute'] ) && $args['attribute'] === $attribute_name_to_hide ) {
            $value_index = array_search( $attribute_value_to_hide, $args['options'] );
            
            if ($value_index !== false) {
                unset($args['options'][$value_index]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```